# IDW(Inverse Distance Weighted) Interpolation in openlayers 6.4.3

Tags: django, interpolation, openlayers, openlayers-6, spatial-interpolation

I have a django3.1 web application with map using ol6 in which I want to show IDW. I have generated an idw image using python & added to map as an image layer but it does not overlay in accurate point positions. So I am looking for a method or technique for overlaying idw as a vector/raster/anything which is correct using ol 6.

Answer (score 1):

The ol-ext extention has an IWD source that lets you create IWD with Openlayers.
See example online: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.layer.idw.html

Comment: I installed ol-ext(3.1.19) using npm and tried to import idw like ***import IDW from 'ol-ext/source';*** but results in error when I build using ***npm run build*** Then I imported from ol ***import IDW from 'ol/source';*** but got error ***Uncaught TypeError: i.default is not a constructor***

Comment: The IWD source is a new feature and not yet deploy on npm. You have to get it directly from the github repo. Make sure you also install ol.